# Validation Message not displaying when submitting non-valid form (ASP.NET Umbraco)

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, validation, umbraco

I followed all the steps in this guide on how to create a functioning form in Umbraco. https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/Code/Creating-Forms/

I then went ahead and added some extra validation, by marking my model properties with [Required] and [EmailAddress], and adding a validation message to my view for each input:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Navn)
```

My controller is set to send an email with the data entered to the input fields. Currently it is non-functional as I need a SMTP client:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(ContactFormViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) //validation
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();

            /// Work with form data here
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add("thomb@hotmail.dk");
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(model.Email);
            mailMessage.Subject = "Kontakt mail";
            mailMessage.Body = "Navn: " + model.Navn + "\nAddresse: " + model.Addresse + ", " + 
                model.PostNrBy + "\nTelefon: " + model.Telefon + "\n\n" + model.Message;
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.your-isp.com");
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
```

My view for the form uses the Umbraco form helper method:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Submit", "ContactForm"))
{
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form class="form-inline" id="kontaktForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Navn</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Navn, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast navn..." })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Navn)
                        <label for="">Addresse</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Addresse, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast addresse..." })
                        <label for="">Postnr. + by</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostNrBy, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast postnr & by..." })
                        <label for="">Telefon</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefon, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast telefonnr..." })
                        <label for="">Email</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast email..." })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <label for="">Skriv din besked</label>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class ="form-control", @id = "kontaktBesked", @rows = "11", @placeholder = "Indtast din besked her..."})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                <button class="btn_1 pull-right contact-btn" name="submit" type="submit">Afsend Besked</button>
                <button class="btn_1 contact-btn">Ryd felter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But when I hit the submit button no validation messages are displayed and the page reloads. Is there a step in validation that I am missing?

Edit: Model added

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Navn { get; set; }

        public string Addresse { get; set; }
        public string PostNrBy { get; set; }
        public string Telefon { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing your model back in the post action? Like `return CurrentUmbracoPage(model)`. And if you want a message, you have to say which message : `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your message")]

Comment: The CurrentUmbracoPage() method does not accept any arguments sadly.

Comment: I'll try adding on the ErrorMessage to the attribute

Comment: Here's what you should do: give the same name to `CurrentUmbracoPage ` and the `Submit`method, like that you can return View(model), but since your post needs an argument they will be different.

Comment: The action method that receives the post. I will put an example in answer, and you tell me if it works

Comment: Thanks, I have done this before with good results in ASP.NET MVC, but not while implementing an Umbraco site. I assumed the workflow would be similar.

Comment: Ah mb, maybe it doesn't work this way in Umbraco.

Answer (score 1):

If you check for ModelState.IsValid and return to currentumbracopage() it should display the error messages.

Otherwise you could use the HTML5 native validation like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast email...", @type="email" })
```

or use a combination of JQuery and HTML5 validation using setCustomValidation on the first element of the input.

**EDIT Added code for jquery with HTML5 validation below**

```
 $('#v[element id]')[0].setCustomValidity("[validation error message]");
```

to make it valid just make the message ""

```
 $('#[element id]')[0].setCustomValidity("");
```